# How to decrease the bigserial value in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using bigserial as as column value in postgres. Now bigserial increments automatically, but I don't want it to increment when same username is entered. Is there a way so that in case of a wrong pg insert value the bigserial won't increase its value.  Or is there a way that I can decrease the value of the bigserial value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrong pg insert'? If it's wrong, either apply contrains to the columns or check before inserting. Don't try to hack a fix to the serial column after the fact.

Comment: sequences are ***never*** guaranteed to be gapless. You shouldn't worry about "missing" values in your table. The column is (most probably) a primary key and thus the actual value of is totally irrelevant.

Comment: What a_horse_with_no_name said with the addition that if you want no gaps in your result set try using the windowing functions.

Comment: If you care *at all* what the actual values of the column are, you should not be using `serial` or `bigserial`. These are non-transactional, non-monotonic, and not necessarily in the order they were committed. Use a traditional counter table instead and accept the resulting bad concurrency. Try a google search for "postgresql gapless sequence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the current value of the associated `SEQUENCE` with either of two methods:

1. With an [SQL statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html):

   ```
   ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq RESTART WITH 12345;
   ```
2. With [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html):

   ```
   SELECT setval('my_seq', 12345, FALSE);
   ```

Take care not to run into duplicate key errors. Note that this does not work well with concurrent transactions. Read the [notes in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html#AEN61687).
This is hardly useful if you want a gap-less sequence of IDs. Mind the comments for that.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to avoid gaps in the sequence numbers. Resetting the sequence to a specific value won't help and will not work with multiple transactions anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's not entirely clear to me what the OP wants. So I answered the actual question asked. I agree, that's probably not what he needs. But it's what people might need who find this question. I'll add a disclaimer concerning gapless sequences.